# Error: "attribute "m_numa_nodes" is not a integer value." when running a qsub snakemake

Tags: snakemake

I am trying to run a snakemake with cluster submission for RNAseq analysis. Here is my script:

```html
#path to gff 
GFF = "RNASeq/data/ref_GRCh38.p2_top_level.gff3"

#sample names and classes
CTHP = 'CTHP1 CTHP2'.split()
CYP = 'CYP1 CYP2'.split()

samples = CTHP + CYP

rule all:
 input:
  'CTHP1/mapping_results/out_summary.gtf',
  'CTHP2/mapping_results/out_summary.gtf',
  'CYP2/mapping_results/out_summary.gtf',
  'CYP1/mapping_results/out_summary.gtf',
  
rule order_sam:
 input:
  '{samples}/mapping_results/mapped.sam'
 output:
  '{samples}/mapping_results/ordered.mapped.bam'
 threads: 12
 params: ppn="nodes=1:ppn=12"
 shell:
  'samtools view -Su {input} | samtools sort > {output}'

rule count_sam:
 input:
  bam='{samples}/mapping_results/ordered.mapped.bam'
 output:
  summary='{samples}/mapping_results/out_summary.gtf',
  abun='{samples}/mapping_results/abun_results.tab',
  cover='{samples}/mapping_results/coveraged.gtf'
 threads: 12
 params: ppn="nodes=1:ppn=12"
 shell:
  'stringtie -o {output.summary} -G {GFF} -C {output.cover} '
  '-A {output.abun} -p {threads} -l {samples} {input.bam}'
```

```

I want to submit each `rule` to a cluster. So, in the Terminal from the working directory, I do this:

`snakemake --cluster "qsub -V -l {params.ppn}" -j 6`

However, the jobs are not submitted and I get following error:

`Unable to run job: attribute "m_numa_nodes" is not a integer value.
Exiting.
Error submitting jobscript (exit code 1):`

I have also tried to set the nodes variable directly when running the snake file like this:

`snakemake --cluster "qsub -V -l nodes=1:ppn=16" -j 6`

and as expected, it gave me the same error. At this point I am not sure if its the local cluster setup or something that I am not doing right in the snake file. Any help would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The error does not look Snakemake related. I am not an SGE/Univa expert so I cannot really help you, but m_numa_nodes is a parameter of the engine. Snakemake does not set it in any way, so it must be either your local configuration or one of the arguments you provide to qsub.

Comment: Thank you! Right now, I have it working with many instances of just single processes. My sys admin guys seems to be in loss as well.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT: 2017/04/12 -- Caught one of the errors in the Google Groups Post. Remove the comma from the last line of input in your "all" rule.**

**EDIT: 2017/04/13 -- Was advised the comma is not an issue **

The beauty of Snakemake is sending it to the cluster just requires additional arguments.To determine if its a Cluster issue, or a Snakemake issue, I  recommend running a dryrun, via

```
snakemake -n
```

Dryrun will not submit any jobs, but it will return the list of jobs. This is a strong indicator if it's a Snakemake issue or a submission issue. I always perform dryruns while in development, to ensure my Snakemake code works before I start trying to submit it to the cluster, because cluster submissions can be a whole different basket of issues.

As per your submission problems, I use the "--drmaa" flag within Snakemake to handle my submissions to the cluster. I realize this is not what you asked for, but I really enjoy its functionality, and I guess I am just suggesting it as a robust alternative to your current approach. 
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/drmaa OR https://anaconda.org/anaconda/drmaa

```
snakemake --jobs 10 --cluster-config input/config.json --drmaa "{cluster.clusterSpec}"
```

Inside config.json, my rules are mostly all provide this parameter set:

```
{
    "__default__": {
        "clusterSpec": "-V -S /bin/bash -o log/varScan -e log/varScan -l h_vmem=10G -pe ncpus 1"
    }
}
```

**SGE Cluster Arguments** = "-V -S /bin/bash -l h_vmem=10G -pe ncpus 1"

**DRMAA Arguments** = "-o log/varScan -e log/varScan"

P.S. I think you have to post as well the Operating System (E.g. CentOS5) and your cluster type(E.g. SGE) you are using.

Comment: The comma at the end of the input file list should be fine.